# Is it possible to specialize a method of a template class on another templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization, template-templates

I have a class `A` that is a template, and I want to specialize the method `foo()` if the class is a `std::vector<T>` with `T` generic, I am getting the error: invalid use of incomplete type. I'd like to avoid writing all specializations for all possible vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename V>
struct A {
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "A<V>\n";
  }
};

template<typename T>
void A<std::vector<T>>::foo() {
  std::cout << "A<V<T>>\n";
}

int main() {
  C<int> a;
  C<std::vector<int>> b;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can either specialize the entire class for vectors, or specialize the function itself using SFINAE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using c++20 contrians:

```
template <typename V>
struct A {
  void foo() { std::cout << "A<V>\n"; }

  void foo() requires (std::same_as<V, std::vector<typename V::value_type>>) {
    std::cout << "A<V<T>>\n";
  }
};
```

Then this works:

```
A<int>{}.foo(); // call normal one
A<std::vector<int>>{}.foo(); // call specialized one
```

Answer (score 1):

If `foo()` doesn't depends from other elements of `A`, you can inherit it through a base class and specialize the base class.

I mean something as follows

```
template <typename>
struct Base
 { void foo() { std::cout << "A<V>\n"; } };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Base<std::vector<Ts...>>
 { void foo() { std::cout << "A<V<Ts...>>\n"; } };

template <typename T>
struct A : public Base<T>
 { };
```

Another possible solution is tag-dispatching: develop two `foo()` functions an "enable" the correct one, according the needs.

For example

```
template <typename>
struct is_vector : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct is_vector<std::vector<Ts...>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct A
 {
   void foo (std::true_type) { std::cout << "A<V<Ts...>>\n"; }

   void foo (std::false_type) { std::cout << "A<V>\n"; }

   void foo () { foo(is_vector<T>{}); } 
 };
```

Comment: With the `is_vector` traits, `if constexpr` (C++17) can be used instead of (old) tag dispatching.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Also with a simple `if`, I suppose, in this particular case. But the question is about specializing a method.